# Test with cypress an custom HTTP Headers

Tags: cypress

I try to build an test with cypress. I need to set a cookie and an custom header field for the test.

With curl, it's easy, like:

```
curl -H "aut: BeUser1"  --cookie "aut=BeUser1" ....
```

But I don't know who to set header and cookie in cypress:

```
cy.setCookie("aut", "BeUser1")
cy.visit("/some/foo");
```

Comment: Are you able to use `cy.request()` instead of `cy.visit()` ?

Comment: Yes I can use it.

Answer (score 7):

Can you try your case as below? Create a `login()` inside commands.js and use `cy.request()` to login to system and add the headers. Also `before` the test, I have run the set cookie as given `cy.setCookie("cookie", "your cookie details here");`

```
Cypress.Commands.add("login", () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    form: true,
    url: 'your-url-here',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',  
      'aut'    : 'BeUser1',       
    },
    body: {       
      "email": "your email",
      //"username": "your username", depends upon your system login you could use email or username
      "password": "your password",
    }
  }).then(response => {
    const target = response.body.email;
  })

})
```

Later on inside the test I have used `cy.getCookie('cookie')` to yield the cookie.

```
describe('Set header and cookie', function() { 
  before('set cookie',function(){
  cy.setCookie("cookie", "add your your cookie here");
  });
    it.only('tests login', function() {
      cy.login();
      cy.getCookie('cookie')
      .then((cookie) => {
          console.log(cookie);
       })
     })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cy.getAllCookie()`. It will return an array of objects of all cookies. Use `then()` as it returns a promise.